# Humans weaker than natives in 0.5g

Tags: microgravity

Im looking to make my world half Earth gravity but I would also like the natives to be strong than an average human ([Acording to google](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=average%20human%20strength))

Would it be possible to have a species stronger than a human in lower gravity?

FYI - Would prefer to be twice as strong but Im not going to nitpick every detail

If it isnt possible you can also make that an answer

Comment: Just remember that big muscles are expensive - why would there be an evolutionary advantage to putting the calories into high strength? Many possibilities are available.

Comment: @pluckedkiwi , I suppose its a good job im not asking why, but if it is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitely possible. Gorillas are estimated to be 6 to 15 times as strong as humans. If gravity has a direct and 1:1 ratio on evolutionary trends towards strength (big assumption here) that means the 0.5g gorilla would have 3 - 7.5 times the strength of the 1.0g human. They would still be slightly bigger.

So definitely possible. However I have the feeling that strength would be less of a trending factor in evolution on a low G planet.

Alternatively, lower G might mean fewer calories are consumed per exertion so greater levels of strength can be more successful.

We need a larger sample size to say for sure. But it is definitely possible.

**Edit**
Well that is all a matter of theory/opinion at this point. But why is strength a positive adaptation? It lets you perform better at the tasks that Jason mentions. However with 2 creatures of equal mass, and all other conditions being equal, less strength is required in a 0.5 g planet to perform the same feats of strength (in most cases). To out perform a creature to the same degree as on a 1.0 g planet requires less muscle mass and strength when you are on the 0.5 g planet. This changes the effect of strength variation on overall survival.

Comment: Ok, good to know I can make something stronger even in low gravity, could you expand on the "strength would be less of a trending factor in evolution on a low G planet"? not sure what you mean by it

Answer (score 2):

Just because gravity is 0.5 gee doesn't change mass. So long as your natives have a need to move high mass things around they will develop strong muscles. A need to sprint, climb quickly, fight other large/own species, etc all select for powerful muscles. Is this species human as well (or very humanoid)? Having to do hard manual labor all day can certainly make even a low gee human stronger than the average earth human without needing to resort to genetic tweaks.

Comment: They are humanoid. That "low gee" made me smile